# How to open PDF file from internal storage in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Used Plugin for the code

```
native_pdf_view: ^4.0.1
```

Sample code where is am getting error, I am able to use pdf file from assets but not able to load pdf from local storage

```
    return Container(
      child: PdfView(
        controller:
            // sample,
            PdfController(
          document: PdfDocument.openFile(widget.path),
        ),
        onDocumentLoaded: (document) {
          setState(() {
            isLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        pageLoader: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
    );
```

error, it says the file was not found but this file path was extracted from the existing file

```
D/PDF_RENDER(  585): OpenFileDocument. File: /storage/emulated/0/Doc_Holder/c4611_sample_explain.pdf
D/PDF_RENDER(  585): OpenAssetDocument. Created file: /data/user/0/com.example.doc_holder/cache/992d7c88890d40268ae7ac4103bf96ba.pdf
D/PDF_RENDER(  585): OpenFileDocument. File: /data/user/0/com.example.doc_holder/cache/992d7c88890d40268ae7ac4103bf96ba.pdf
D/PDF_RENDER(  585): OpenFileDocument. File: /storage/emulated/0/Doc_Holder/c4611_sample_explain.pdf

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building PdfView(dirty, state: _PdfViewState#6990d):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
PdfView
lib/const/pdf.dart:23
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _PdfViewState._buildLoaded
package:native_pdf_view/src/native_pdf_view.dart:172
#1      _PdfViewState.build
package:native_pdf_view/src/native_pdf_view.dart:205
#2      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4683
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4566
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4738
...
```

Comment: Sometimes when you do something incorrectly with assets and fix it afterwards, it doesn't work until you delete and reinstall the app on your emulator, so try that

Comment: I tried that but its still giving same error. Error causing widget in 2nd line pdfView()
And when i am trying to open a pdf from assets folder of the project its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Please try any of them

pdf: ^3.3.0,
flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6,
syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^19.1.58-beta,
syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer_platform_interface: ^19.1.58-beta